# Cannot drag an inline visualforce page onto a standard page layout

Tags: visualforce, inline-visualforce

I want to embed a visualforce page inside a standard layout. Both page and extension are fine (Preview is working).
Controller -

```
    public with sharing class ExpenseExtension{

        private final expense_report__c repo;
        public expenseExtension(ApexPages.StandardController std){
            this.repo = (expense_report__c)std.getRecord();
          }

        public list<expense_item__c> getItems(){

            return [select serial__c, Appointment__c, AppointDate__c, Mode_of_Travel__c, Kms_Travelled__c, Expense_Incurred__c from
                    expense_item__c where expense_report__c = :repo.id];
        }
}
```

Visualforce -

```
<apex:page standardController="Expense_Report__c" extensions="ExpenseExtension">
<apex:pageBlock title="Expense Items" >
   <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!items}" var="item" width="900px">
      <apex:column value="{!item.Serial__c}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!item.Appointment__c}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!item.AppointDate__c}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!item.Mode_of_Travel__c}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!item.Kms_Travelled__c}"/>
      <apex:column value="{!item.Expense_Incurred__c}"/>
   </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

When I try dragging the page I don't see any placeholder on the standard layout. What's the reason? What I'm missing, obviously I would like to have my inline page above the Approval History list.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first add a `Section` or `Blank Space` into which you will drag your `VisualForce Page`. You can then drag the page into either of these.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi Adrian, I have added the page section and dropped my visualforce page. Now I can only see my visualforce page and the whole standard layout has been overridden. Even after editing the page layout and removing the section is not working, I can only see the inline vf page for the whole record.

Comment: Did you inadvertently override the `View` action at some point in your experimentation? Check `Create` > `Objects` > `Expense_Report__c` > `Buttons, Links, and Actions`.